# jquery to fetch the contents from a selected row in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is the source code , its not able to fetch the selected content when i check the checbox rather its taking all the contents from the table ... Can anyone spot what mistake is in my code... thanks for ur time

```
for(k=0;k<=9000;k++) {

    //each change

    $("#status"+k).click(function() {

        for(j=0;j<=numOflimit;j++) {

            var product_name = encodeURIComponent($('#product_name'+j).val());
            alert(product_name);
            var barcode = encodeURIComponent($('#barcode'+j).val());
            var Quantity = encodeURIComponent($('#Quantity'+j).val());
            var cart=product_name + barcode + Quantity;
            alert(cart);
            $('#cart1').val(cart);  

        }

    });


});
```

Comment: I've fixed indentation. There seems to be an extra `);` after `}` at the very end.

Comment: Also, why are you `encodeURIComponent()` a value that you put back into an input, (`#cart1`)? If you `serialize()` the form via jQuery, or submit it normally, the encoding is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops here. The outer one seems to attach a click handler to all rows (or to the checkboxes of each row). The inner one however makes no sense. It's result is that no matter what checkbox you click, it will iterate over all rows and collect the values.