# jquery and php to grab the contents from a selected row When onclick of a selected checbox

Tags: php, jquery, html

Attached the source code of PHP and jquery , gives undefined as alert ...later displays all the contents in the table... i need to just display the one which the user clicks on checkbox..... what mistake is in my code.

--------------------php---------------------------------------------------------

```
   </script>
     <script src="<?=base_url();?>js/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <form name="inwardProductList" action="" method="post" >
          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center"  class="formtable">
              <tr>
                <td height="23" colspan="8" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><b>Cart Display</b></td>
              </tr>

   <tr>
     <td height="66" align="left" valign="top"><table width="99%" id="suppliedtable" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
            <td width="4%" height="43" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Sl.no</strong></td>
            <td width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Product Name</strong></strong></td>
            <td width="20%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Barcode</strong></td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Quantity</strong></strong></td>
            <td width="8%" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#e7e6e6" class="rows"><strong>Select</strong></strong></td>
           </tr>
      <?        
      $i=0;
if($productName->num_rows() >0){

  foreach($productName->result() as $row ){
    $i++;   
     ?>

          <tr>
            <td  align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$i;?></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row->product_name?></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_name<?=$i?>" id="product_name<?=$i?>" class="button" value="<?=$row ->product_name;?>"/>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><?=$row->barcode?></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="barcode<?=$i?>" id="barcode<?=$i?>" class="button" value="<?=$row ->barcode;?>"/>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><form><input type="text" name="Quantity<?=$i;?>" id="Quantity<?=$i;?>" /></form></td>
            <td align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><form>
                           <input type="checkbox" name="status<?=$i;?>" id="status<?=$i;?>" value="yes" /> <br /></form></td>

        </tr>

      <? }}else{?>
    <tr>
                <td height="23" colspan="8" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="rows"><b>Selected product has not been processed yet</b></td>
    </tr>
   <?}?>
  </table></td>
   </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="numOflimit" id="numOflimit" class="button" value="<?=$i?>"/>

     <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="cart1" id="cart1"></td></tr>
</table>
 <form><tr><td  align="center" > <button onclick="go()">Submit</button></td> </tr>
 <tr> <td id="cart"> </td> </tr>
 <div id="test"></div>
 </form></form>
 </form>
```

----------------------jquery code----------------------------------------------

```
      for(k=0;k<=9000;k++)
{   //each change

    $("#status"+k).change(function () {

        var numOflimit = encodeURIComponent($('#numOflimit').val());
        //alert(numOflimit);

    for(j=0;j<=numOflimit;j++)
        {

        var product_name = encodeURIComponent($('#product_name'+j).val());
        //alert(product_name);
        var barcode = encodeURIComponent($('#barcode'+j).val());
        var Quantity = encodeURIComponent($('#Quantity'+j).val());
        //var unitBag = encodeURIComponent($('#unitBag'+k).val());
    //var postData = $("form").serialize();
    //  alert(postData);
        var cart=product_name + barcode + Quantity;
        alert(cart);
        $('#cart1').val(cart);  
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a full working example up somewhere, so we can actually try it? Debugging an undefined error in JavaScript just by looking at a code snippet is not the easiest thing in the world.

You might also want to open the JavaScript error console in Firefox and check the errors tab straight after the alert appears, as that might give you a useful pointer as to where the error is (e.g. you've forgotten to define a variable somewhere). The Firebug plugin may also help: http://getfirebug.com/

Edit: Just noticed that this seems to be a duplicate of another question:

[jquery to fetch the contents from a selected row in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772490/jquery-to-fetch-the-contents-from-a-selected-row-in-php)